# How to access a variable in a custom type Generic List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `HashSet<T>`, a `List<T>` and a class.

`Relayhash` contains a set of `Vector3` variables. Used as a list for input, usually one variable is picked either randomly or via another rule.

`tempList` To temporarily store `vector3` variables for comparison.

`BuiltList` contains a set of custom class types serves as the destination of selected variables.Here, I would like to find out if it contains a certain variable (posv3).

```
HashSet<Vector3> relayhash = new HashSet<Vector3>();
List<Vector3> tempList = new List<Vector3>();
public List<moduleClass> BuildList = new List<moduleClass>(); 


  public class moduleClass
{
    public int step { get; set; }
    public int modID { get; set; }
    public string modType { get; set; }
    public int typeint { get; set; }
    public Vector3 posv3 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to find out if `relayhash` contains a Vector that is already in `BuildList`. If true, then the found Vector3(s) needs to be removed from 'relayHash'.

These are some of the scripts I've tried:

```
 Vector3 tempvar =  moduleClass.posv3; // ClassName.VariableName does not work, why?
```

or,

```
foreach (Vector3 tempv3 in relayhash)// 
{
moduleClass tempvar = new moduleClass();
if (BuildList.Contains(tempvar.tempv3))// not accepted, 'does not contain a definition..)
{// do something}
}
```

or,

```
foreach (Vector3 tempv3 in relayhash)// 
        {
            moduleClass tempvar = new moduleClass();
            Vector3 tempv = tempvar.posv3;
            tempv = tempv3;

            if (BuildList.Contains(tempv)):// but, cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'mods.moduleClass'
            {
                //   var tempvar = new moduleClass(posv3);
                //  tempList.Add(tempv3);
            }
        }
```

And a lot of variations of the examples above, but I cannot see the forest for the trees. I'm not getting the syntax right, despite having looked up and tried many similar variations of examples.

So my question is: how can a variable within a list of custom types be accessed (and compared to the same type in another list)?

Thanks for looking.

ps:

The main issue is now that it's not possible to remove a found Vector from the 'relayhash'. For example:

```
var foundVectors = relayhash.Intersect(BuildList.Select(x => x.posv3));

relayhash.Remove(foundVectors);
```

Results in:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.Vector3>' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Vector3` , does it implement `IEquatable`? But BuildList won't contain tempV3 as BuildList is if type moduleClass, don't time to look at it fully right now but start looking at BuildList.posv3

Comment: @D Stanley
Thanks a ton!

I tried:

var foundItems = BuildList.Where(x => relayhash.Contains(x.posv3));

var foundVectors = foundItems.Select(x => x.posv3);

Also,

var foundVectors = relayhash.Intersect(BuildList.Select(x => x.posv3));

Either option does not allow a vector to be removed fr relayHash:

relayhash.Remove(foundVectors);

It results in: 

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.Vector3>' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Can I remove a vector using the first example? 

bool found = BuildList.Any(x => relayhash.Contains(x.posv3));

Comment: @d219 Thanks! I don't know about IEquatable

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find out if 'relayhash' contains a Vector that is already in 'BuildList'.

More specifically, you want to see if `relayhash` contains a `Vector3` *that is equal to the value of `posv3` of any item in `BuildList`*. Does that help to see how the query should be structured?

You can us `Any` on either list, but since `relayhash` is already a `HashSet`, which does cheap `Contains` checks, a more performant way may be to use `Any` on the list of custom objects:

```
bool found = BuildList.Any(x => relayhash.Contains(x.posv3));
```

If you want to capture the actual *objects*, then a `Where` may be more appropriate:

```
var foundItems = BuildList.Where(x => relayhash.Contains(x.posv3));
```

You can then capture the v3 items from the filteres list:

```
var foundVectors = foundItems.Select(x => x.posv3);
```

or do an `Intersect`:

```
var foundVectors = relayhash.Intersect(BuildList.Select(x => x.posv3));
```

Comment: The question here is what kind of equality is needed? This answer works for referential equality only. You might want to clarify how to get the value equality, if that is what is expected.

Comment: @insane_developer [`UnityEngine.Vector3`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs) is a struct, and also implements `IEquatable<Vector3>` so I'm assuming that the default definition of "equal" is desired.

Comment: Sure, a struct will do just that. I'm not familiar with Unity so I assumed it could be a class. Good to know. Thanks.